# need help understanding how python arrays work

Tags: python, arrays

So I'm trying to create an array visualiser with pygame and have run into a strange problem I can't seem to get around,

here's a small portion of code to recreate the issue

```
def appendto(array):
    temp=[]
    for i in range(3):
        array.append(i)
        temp.append(array)
    return temp

array=[]
print(appendto(array))
```

When I run this code it shows

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

I am trying to make the temp array record each change made to the main array, but by the end it seems to have only recorded the final state of the array 3 times.

The only half - solution I have found is to turn the array into a string before appending it, doing

```
array.append(str(i))
```

but this will slow down my program significantly as I will then have to turn the string back into an array in order to use it.

please do tell me if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: You add the same array to `temp` three times. The fact that you're modifying the array in between doesn't change the fact that it's the same object, being represented three times.

Comment: What you probably intend to do is add a copy of the array at a certain point in time. You can do that by doing either `array.copy()` or `array[:]`.

Comment: The first thing you need to understand is that Python assigns object by their reference, *not by value*.  Each time you append `array` to `temp`, it is assigning the actual object of `array` into `temp` so in reality you are seeing the same copy of the object 3 times.  Just do a `[id(x) for x in temp]` and you'll understand.  As @GreenCloakGuy said, if you want the value at the time of the loop, use `array.copy()` instead (which creates a separate copy object of `array` but will not be affected in later iteration of the loop).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I closed the question because it's practically the same as an existing question. The only difference is that the new reference to the list is in the form of a list element (`temp[i]`) instead of a name (`new_list`). BTW, this is a good first question! though the title could be more specific. For tips, see [ask].

Comment: BTW, this is a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists), not an array. Arrays are different, like [NumPy arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html) or [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think adding a `print()` statement in your `for` loop might help illustrate what is going on.

```
def appendto(array):
    temp=[]
    for i in range(3):
        array.append(i)
        temp.append(array)
        print(temp)
    return temp

array=[]
print(appendto(array))
```

This will give you:

```
[[0]]
[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

We can see that appending items to `array` cascades though all references to `array`. To be clear, there is only one `array` we just now have a list of three items all pointing to it.

What you probably want to do is append a copy.

```
def appendto(array):
    temp=[]
    for i in range(3):
        array.append(i)
        temp.append(array.copy())
    return temp

array=[]
print(appendto(array))
```

giving you:

```
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: oh wow I would have never thought that it does that, thanks